# Get true/false of json lint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codemirror, lint

I have ui-codemirror implemented in my angular app. I have lint turned on. How can I grab a value of lint validation (like true or false if there is an error)?

Comment: So you want to run some kind of linter inside of your webpage?

Comment: @MikeC Yeah I have lint in codemirror to validate JSON wrote inside